# How to create and remove an HTML hidden field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

First of all here is my code so that you can test it to see what's wrong: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw4e/1/)

I want to create a new hidden field every time the user selects from the left `<select>` element and remove / destroy the hidden field when the user clicks the right `<select>` element.

I used the jQuery command `$("<input type='hidden' value=selectedAddFootballPlayerId>");` but when I checked of Firebug I can't see any hidden field being created. For removal of the hidden field I really don't know.

Comment: It's not enough to just create the element, you have to place it somewhere on the page as well.

Comment: So you mean I really have to make at least one hidden field? What I want to happen is that whenever a user adds a football player that's the time a hidden value will be created to hold the value of the selected football player.

Comment: please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused when defining the selector or where you want to display your new item. Try with this (I use text inputs):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw4e/6/

Answer (score 7):

For this you can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("body").append("<input type='hidden' value=selectedAddFootballPlayerId>");
```

For removal, use  [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$("input[type='hidden']").remove();
```

Be careful when using my example, as it'll remove all form elements that are hidden. If you want more prescision, you can assign an `id` value to the hidden input and then call that as your selector in the second example.

Answer (score 6):

To create -

```
var $ip = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'yourid',
    name: 'yourname',
    value: 'yourvalue' 
})
$(ip).appendTo('body');
```

Then to remove -

```
$ip.remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the field:

```
$("<input type='hidden' value=selectedAddFootballPlayerId>").appendTo('#someSelector');
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't mind any html validity when appending, it will just do it. So it doesn't matter if it's a div or a select or something else :)

Answer (score 2):

Working version

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzw4e/7/

Changes

1

```
$("<input type='hidden' value=selectedAddFootballPlayerId>");
to
$('body').append("<input type='hidden' value=\""+selectedAddFootballPlayerId+"\">");
```

2

```
$('#listboxFootballPlayers').append(option);
to
$('#listboxFootballPlayers').append(option);
$('input[type="hidden"][value="'+selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: No problem, dont forget to add that input a name, if your working with array probably `player` or `player[]` will be needed to process that information

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" id="input-image{{ image_row }}" />

inputt= "<input type="hidden" name="product_image' value="abcd">"

$("#input-image"+row).remove().append(inputt);
```